# Find Area of Similar Right Triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles, gre-exam

Need help to approach following from GRE study guide

[image]

Here is what I have so far

$area = 1/2 bh$

$area CDE = 1/2 bh = 42 = 21 bh$

$AD = 3CD$

Honestly, I'm not sure how to approach. Please give hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As triangles $CDE$ and $ADG$ are similar, and you are given that $AD=3CD$, what can you say about the relationship between sides $AG$ and $CE$, and between sides $DG$ and $DE$?

Comment: I believe $AG = 3CE$ and $DG = 3DE$. At first, I thought area would be $3  x  42 = 126$, but it's something else.

Comment: Yes, you are right about $AG$ and $DG$, but don't forget that the area is half times base times height as you wrote down. So, the area will be $3\times 3\times 42$.

Comment: I don't understand .... how did you get $3 * 3 * 42$

Comment: The area of the smaller triangle $CDE$ is $\frac{1}{2}\times CE \times DE$. Now the area of the larger triangle $ADG$ is $\frac{1}{2}\times AG \times DG=\frac{1}{2}\times (\color{blue}{3}CE) \times (\color{blue}{3}DE)=\color{blue}{3\times 3}\times \frac{1}{2}\times CE \times DE$.

Comment: Now I understand!

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

I would say, split image:

[image]

Comment: Yes, if I split image it is $42 x 9 = 378$, but what if image wasn't drawn to scale? Kindly explain concepts.

Comment: @SohniMahiwal    "but what if image wasn't drawn to scale"  ???:   Small triangles have the same hypotenuse, and two angles -> are identical.